# Con un SWITCH-CASE ¿Cómo se hace un pulsador de encendido ON/OFF asimétrico con dos pulsaciones para encender y una pulsación para apagar?

Tags: c++, funciones, arduino

Estoy programando el funcionamiento de un exposímetro termico y para el encendido de éste necesito una función de un pulsador que lo encienda cuando pulso durante un segundo y después vuelvo a pulsar durante otro segundo, para apagar es con una pulsación de 5 segundos y obligatoriamente tengo que utilizar un switch-case. Por ahora lo enciendo con una pulsación de 1 segundo y lo apago con una pulsacion de 5 segundos utilizando if-else(Os lo dejo abajo), pero me piden que lo haga con un switch-case y dos pulsaciones pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, a pesar de varios intentos no me funciona ninguno.

```
{
  currentTime=millis();
  int timeON=1000;
  int timeOFF=5000;
  if(digitalRead(buttonPin)==LOW)
  {
    if(ledState==false)
    {
      //Ponemos el tiempo que debe estar pulsado para que entre en la siguiente condicion
      if(((currentTime-startTime)>=timeON)&&(condition==false))
      {
        ledState=true;//Encendido del LED
        startTime=currentTime;//Actualización del tiempo de inicio.
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //Ponemos el tiempo que debe estar pulsado para que entre en la siguiente condicion
      if(((currentTime-startTime)>=timeOFF)&&(condition==true))
      {
        ledState=false;
        startTime=currentTime;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if(ledState==true)
    {
      condition=true;
    }
    if(ledState==false)
    {
      condition=false;
    }
    startTime=currentTime;//Esto nos sirve para qiue el tiempo se vaya actualizando cuando no estemos pulsando
  }
  return(ledState);
}
```

Comment: Siempre que leas un botón, pulsador o interruptor mecánico, tienes que hacer debouncing para filtrar la señal.

Answer (score 0):

en un `switch` puedes evaluar los valores que quieras siempre se los mismos sean numéricos o caracteres `char`.

Así, podrías usar `switch` para evaluar el valor devuelto por `digitalRead` (por poner un ejemplo)

```
switch( digitalRead(buttonPin) )
{
case LOW:
    if(ledState==false)
    {
      //Ponemos el tiempo que debe estar pulsado para que entre en la siguiente condicion
      if(((currentTime-startTime)>=timeON)&&(condition==false))
      {
        ledState=true;//Encendido del LED
        startTime=currentTime;//Actualización del tiempo de inicio.
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //Ponemos el tiempo que debe estar pulsado para que entre en la siguiente condicion
      if(((currentTime-startTime)>=timeOFF)&&(condition==true))
      {
        ledState=false;
        startTime=currentTime;
      }
    }
    break;

case HIGH:
   condition = ledState;
   startTime = currentTime;
   break;
}
```